# Gpg4Win batch asymmetric encryption from Windows service with LocalSystem account

Tags: windows, service, gnupg, asymmetric

I'd like run the Duplicati backup soft as a Windows service for 2 reasons : gather all users files and run even no one is logged in. Also, even if the system was a single user one, I wouldn't like to rely on supplying the user's Windows password either to the service or a scheduled on-boot job, because if user changes his password, then he must remember to update the service or job.

I first tested (seemed OK) from within a user account i.e. not as a service, with a small subset of the user's files with these parameters and a private key with no passphrase:

`--no-default-keyring --keyring c:\users\utilisateur\AppData\Roaming\gnupg\pubring.kbx --default-key FULLFINGERPRINTHERE --default-recipient-self`

When ran as a service I get this error (translated to english):

`GPG execution failure with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Gpg4win\..\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --no-default-keyring --keyring c:\users\utilisateur\AppData\Roaming\gnupg\pubring.kbx --default-key FULLFINGERPRINTHERE --default-recipient-self --encrypt": gpg: Warning: not using 'FULLFINGERPRINTHERE' as default key: No gpg secret key: all values passed to '--default-key' ignored gpg: no valid recipient gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: No identity`

Please notice the parameters `--batch --passphrase-fd 0 --encrypt` added by Duplicati. I added `--no-default-keyring` & `--keyring path-to-user-gpg-data` as a workaround to `--secret-keyring <file>` being obsolete in gpgv2 because secret keys are now stored in `private-keys-v1.d` directory.

Please any hint ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with `--home-dir path` and removed the --[no-default-]keyring stuff. First I didn't try because the manual says it is only considered in command line.

Comment: It think it should be --homedir